# Software to flip vector graphic without the use of CSS or SVG code

Tags: vector, svg, software-recommendation, transform

Say I have a simple SVG file, as an example, this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none">
  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="orange"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Visually:

[image: Original SVG]

**I want to flip this vertically, but without the use of CSS or SVG code. E.g., without using `transform` attribute or similar functionality in CSS. Is there any tool/software that can achieve this?**

The reason for this desire is that if I use `transform` then any sub-elements in the SVG will also adhere to this flip, and I'll have to "counterflip" to keep the original look. For example if I added a triangle to the original image:

[image: Original SVG with triangle]

Then flipping the `g` element using `transform="scale(1, -1) translate(0, -100)"` will end up flipping both:

[image: Original SVG with triangle, flipped vertically]

I realize that perhaps you can group elements different and such to solve it, but ideally and for this question I have a tool that can flip the SVG graphics so that I can save it again and avoid having to use transform for this particular adjustment.

Comment: Practically **any** vector application can "flip" things.. Illustrator, Inkscape, Sketch, Affinity...

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what the problem is here.  Most vector image editors such as Illustrator or Inkscape can do this. Don't make any groups. No need to flip the rectangle either, just move it. Don't use transforms.

Comment: Here are a couple of examples. [Example 1](https://svgshare.com/i/zcd.svg) and [Example 2](https://svgshare.com/i/zbw.svg)

Comment: Thank you. I'm fairly sure the issue here is I'm a software developer with little graphics design experience. Are any of these decent vector softwares on a free plan? Most online Googleable tools I've tried in browser make this edit as a code edit, not a graphical one.

Comment: Inkscape is Free and Open Source. Illustrator is paid software made by Adobe

Comment: If you are going to use Inkscape, there's a slight learning curve. I recommend this tutorial to help get you started: [on youtube from LogosByNick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzk-suGcqrc). I have no affiliation with this channel or the youtuber.